# Module not found: Can't resolve ' react' in ' path'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I had this error which occured while running my project;
`Module not found: Can't resolve ' react' in`
I tried several methods to resolve this problem . First of all I had the correct state in my component ;
I imported react earlier .. Then , I deleted `node_modules` and run `npm install` In VAIN !!

Secondly I tried to remove package-log.json and run `npm install` and type `npm clear cache` !! However It doesn't work too . I got stucked and I dont know what to do !!

Comment: can you post terminal screenshot or some code where its showing error?

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve ' react' in ````C:\Users\{UserName}\Desktop\.....\src\components````  @hafizali

Comment: Given that the error message is "Can't resolve ' react'..." rather than "Can't resolve 'react'...", the problem is quite probably because there is a space before `react` somewhere in your project.  Does your project perhaps contain a line similar to `import React, { Component } from ' react';`, with a space before `react`?

Comment: yeahhh thankksss a Lot the space before !!  @hafizali

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have this problem.

To install React, type these commands :

npx create-react-app my-app
npm start

For more informations, go there : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I typed npx create-react-app and when i run my project it doesnt work

Comment: Have you install node.js before ?